# What are the MVC components in the context of web development?

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

I'm trying to understanding what MVC is, why it's useful, and if I should use it or not.

In the context of dynamic websites, what are the models, views, and controllers? I've seen these as examples before, are they all right or is only one of them right?

- Model: HTML, view: CSS, controller: Javascript
- Model: database, backend processing; view: HTML, CSS, Javascript;
  controller: HTTP (GET/POST), URLs
- Model: database; view: HTML, CSS, Javascript; controller: backend
  processing

Are there other examples of MVC in web development?

Answer (score 2):

This is a mega-vague question, but here's one generalization...

- **Controller** (JavaScript): Listens to clicks and notifies methods on your model/view-model.
- **Model** (JavaScript): This encapsulates methods for serializing/deserializing data from sources like a database, public API, whatever.
- **ViewModel** (JavaScript): This handles formatting data in your model for display by your view (e.g. pretty-formatting names, emails, numbers, etc)
- **View** (HTML+CSS): This is what the user sees. It shows information that's described by your view-model and dispatches events that are listened to by your controller.

Comment: As to why it's useful: it helps structure code and separate concerns.

Comment: And separating concerns is good because it helps you write leaner, more focused automated tests. If you do it correctly, you'll be able to test each individual component using stubbed/mocked versions of the other components.